# How do I get my baked UV map to apply to the object

Tags: texturing

Complete Newb here. I have an unwrapped UV map which I baked with color diffuse. I can see the finished colors in render preview, and they look exactly like I want them to, but when I save the blend file, and upload the model to sketchfab or any other 3d website, or send the blend file to a friend, the color textures are gone. How do I apply them to my finished model so that they remain part of the blend file? I'm sure I'm making some very simple mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The baked image needs to be saved, then opened in the blend file, then packed into the blend file.  Give me a bit, I'll post an answer with images & details.

Comment: @KickAir8p,I have the same problem.Eg, create a susan, I put two material on it by vertices group, I want to have a picture output as a whole material, so if I want to create a susan later, I don't need to set the vertices group again and use two material, I only need to add the picture I saved and the result will show the same.

Comment: @NatureK I'm not sure that's the same problem.  If my answer below helps then good, otherwise it sounds like you have a baking issue.  If searching through previous answers doesn't resolve it then you should probably post a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In this example I've just baked a Voronoi Texture on Suzanne to an image.  To avoid losing the baked image I need to either save the image outside of the blend file:

[image]

Or pack the image into the blend file before saving the blend file:

[image]

Tip:  if you've saved the image and then used it as an image texture then you need to pack it into the blend file before saving it if you want it included in the blend file when you send it to somebody.

Comment: sorry，it's not what I want...  I have 
 a cube with 3 materials in 3 slots, I want to make an image texture that can shade the cube the same as 3 material shows. Here's the demo,thanks~https://pasteall.org/blend/3ed3e89433514f67b1a9cf7d71ef9840

Comment: In what way is it different? As KickAir8p says, you first need to bake, it will give you one image, and you'll have to save or pack this image.

Comment: @moonboots, but I can't bake the picture of those 3 colors made by 3 material in 3 slots.The bake can only recognize one slot, but 3 material are in 3 slots, so 2 of them will lost.

Comment: I've written an answer, I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. This completely solved my problem, and I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

To answer NatureK's specific question (and not original poster's question):

Create an *Image Texture* node and give it an new image that you'll call *Bake* for example. Copy paste this node in each of your materials, don't plug them into the *Principled BSDF* of your materials. If you had other *Image Texture* in your materials you would have to keep these *Image Texture* nodes selected in each material but it's not the case here. Bake, it will save each color of each face onto your image:

[image]

Now you can create a new material that will be the *Image Texture* plugged into the *Principled BSDF*, give this material to the whole cube, remove the other materials, and pack the image so that it is part of the file.

Comment: That's really what I want! The key is 3 image texture! Thank you so so so much!

Comment: oops I confused you with the original poster, are you the same person?

Comment: No,sorry...When I read the question and comment,I find out that maybe the knowledge he has can help me,so I asked a little more in detail instead of open a new question.